# Django : two users in rating form instance

Tags: django

I got a simple question. I don't understand how I get for `rate_form.instance.sugar` the `sugargroup.seller`. As `RateSugar` is related to `Sugargroup` I could normally do it. Bu I don't find the answer...

Only user (which is consumer) can post the form. That's why I've `used self.request.user`

views.py

```
class CheckoutDetail(generic.DetailView, FormMixin):
model = Sugargroup
context_object_name = 'sugargroup'
template_name = 'checkout_detail.html'
form_class = CreateSugarChatForm
rate_form_class = RateSugarForm

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(CheckoutDetail, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['form'] = self.get_form()
    context['rate_form'] = self.get_form(self.rate_form_class)
    return context

def form_valid(self, form):
    if form.is_valid():
        form.instance.sugargroup = self.object
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        form.save()
        return super(CheckoutDetail, self).form_valid(form)
    else:
        return super(CheckoutDetail, self).form_invalid(form)
        
def form_valide(self, rate_form):
    if rate_form.is_valid():
        rate_form.instance.relationto = self.object
        rate_form.instance.sugar = self.relationto.seller **# issue 'CheckoutDetail' object has no attribute 'relationto'**
        rate_form.instance.cooker = self.request.user
        rate_form.save()
        return super(CheckoutDetail, self).form_valide(rate_form)
    else:
        return super(CheckoutDetail, self).form_invalide(rate_form)        

def post(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
    self.object = self.get_object()
    form = self.get_form()
    rate_form = self.get_form(self.rate_form_class)
    if form.is_valid():
        return self.form_valid(form)
    elif rate_form.is_valid():
        return self.form_valide(rate_form)
    else:
        return self.form_valid(form)

def get_success_url(self):
    return reverse('checkout:checkout_detail',kwargs={"slug":self.object.slug})
```

models.py

```
class Ratesugar(models.Model):
    relationto = models.OneToOneField(Sugargroup,on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True, related_name="ratesugar_relationto")
    sugar = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='ratesugar_sugar')
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='ratesugar_cooker')
    ...

class Sugargroup(models.Model):
    consumer = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="sugargroup_consumer", blank=True, null=True)
    seller = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="sugargroup_seller")
```

Comment: I don't really follow *why* you need the seller. If your `Ratesugar` model has a reference to the `Sugargroup`, then if you want the seller, you can later access it through `self.relationto.seller`. This removes data duplication in the database, and thus prevents the database getting in an inconsistent state where the `Ratesugar` refers toa  different seller than the `seller` of the `Sugargroup` it refers to.

Comment: thanks for your response @WillemVanOnsem but I got this 'CheckoutDetail' object has no attribute 'relationto'. I'm using tow form in on views. I update the views

Comment: Can you please include the *full* view.

Comment: Yes :) I do it right now

Comment: notice that `self` is the instance. I'm not talking about the form. It is more about mismodeling, where you give the database possibilities to end up in an inconsistent state.

Comment: `return super(CheckoutDetail, self).form_valide(rate_form)` furthermore does not exists either.

Comment: The `post` method also will first check if the first form is valid, and if not, continue with the second form. Only if both forms are invalid, it will assume that the data is invalid. But this does not look ok, since you probably want both forms to be valid.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to change them. I'd like to use them separately. First is a chat and second is a rate (after order)

Comment: in case the two forms are "indpedent". I would strongly advise to use two separate views to handle the request. You can specify `<form action="some-view">` for the first and `<form action="some-other-view">` for the latter. That way you *simplify* your views.

Comment: Is it possible to use it on the same page with different views? Have you got a tuto on this?

Comment: I've changed my plan with separate page & view for the form.